# Bash ls and command pipe

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line-arguments, ls

I'm trying to use the `/etc/passwd` file to list home directories of users in the system, sorted and without repetitions, such that nonexisting directories would not be printed..
This is my command:

```
cut -f 6 -d ':' /etc/passwd | sort -su | ls -ld
```

It acts as if I just ran `ls -ld` with no arguments from the command pipe at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pipe stuff into `ls`.. You could do something like:

```
ls -ld $(cut -f 6 -d ':' /etc/passwd | sort -su)
```

By spawning a new bash to execute the `cut | sort` and passing it as a `ls` argument

Comment: Thanks, this works!
Earlier i tried `ls -ld $("cut -f 6 -d ':' /etc/passwd | sort -su")` and bash said that its an unknown command, why?

Comment: Maybe because you passed the command to `$( )` in `" "` as a string.. You should pass the command directly ;)

Answer (score 4):

`ls` does not take piped output. You could, however, use forward quotes to execute it on a list of directories:

```
ls `cut -f 6 -d ':' /etc/passwd | sort -su `
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `xargs`

```
cut -f 6 -d ':' /etc/passwd | sort -su | xargs ls
```

Answer (score 2):

You were not far away, it was enough to add a xargs before ls :

```
cut -f 6 -d ':' /etc/passwd | sort -u | xargs ls -ld
```